# reducing an array of nested objects in javascript

Tags: nested, javascript-objects, reduce

so i have this array and i want to return the sum of lci and the sum of mci with a reduce function

```
const data = [{ option:{ lci: 1, mci: 2 } }, { option:{ lci: 3, mci: 4 } }, { option:{ lci: 5, mci: 6 } }];
```

i have tried this but it's not working:

```
 data.reduce( (previousValue, currentValue) => {
    return {
      totalLCI: previousValue.option.lci + currentValue.option.lci,
      totalMCI: previousValue.option.lci + currentValue.option.lci,
    };
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

reduce method takes 2 important args: your reducing function and the default value at step 0 of the iteration

Here the reducer has 2 args:

- the so-called `previousValue`: here called `reducerTarget` as it receives what is returned in the body of the reducer
- the `currentValue` where the reducer is: here called `currentArrayItem`

Here's what you might want

```js
    const {totalLCI, totalMCI} = data.reduce((reducerTarget, currentArrayItem) => { 
        return {
            totalLCI: reducerTarget.totalLCI + currentArrayItem.option.lci,
            totalMCI: reducerTarget.totalMCI + currentArrayItem.option.mci
        }
    }, {totalLCI: 0, totalMCI: 0})
```

From here, starting with the default value, what it does on the first iteration is

```js
/* 1st step: 
    index = 0
    targetReducer = defaultValue = {totalMCI: 0, totalLCI: 0}
    currentArrayItem = {option: {lci: 1, mci: 2}}
*/
        return {
            totalLCI: 0 + 1,
            totalMCI: 0 + 2
        }

/* 2nd step: 
    index = 1
    targetReducer = previousValue = {totalMCI: 1, totalLCI: 2}
    currentArrayItem = {option: {lci: 3, mci: 4}}
*/
        return {
            totalLCI: 1 + 3,
            totalMCI: 2 + 4
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need know if you have stored value in the fields `totalLCI` and `totalMCI`, if they aren't set, add the **previous** value and the **current** value, after add, return the values, in the next iteration, you will check again if the data is stored in `totalLCI` and `totalMCI`, after that, you will get data stored in that field and sum it all the time till finish the iteration, here an example:

```js
var data2 = [{ option:{ lci: 1, mci: 2 } }, { option:{ lci: 3, mci: 4 } }, { option:{ lci: 5, mci: 6 } }];

let test = data2.reduce( (previousValue, currentValue) => {
    
    if(!previousValue.totalLCI && !previousValue.totalMCI){

        return {
          totalLCI: previousValue.option.lci + currentValue.option.lci,
          totalMCI: previousValue.option.mci + currentValue.option.mci
        };
    }else{
        return{
            totalLCI: previousValue.totalLCI + currentValue.option.lci,
            totalMCI: previousValue.totalMCI + currentValue.option.mci
        }

    }
  });



console.log(test.totalLCI);
console.log(test.totalMCI);
```